# Firebase queries don't work for signed android apk

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I download the signed apk for my android app and login using correct credentials, the authentication fails. However, for the same package, when I download the debug APK and directly run the same on a real device, the same credentials work. On the emulator, the firebase related queries work, but on running the signed APK it always fails.

[image: Here is the logs when I run my signed apk]

Here is the specific error message:

> E  Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - An internal error has occurred. [ Requests from this Android client application com.cfc.cfc are blocked. ]

I double checked the signing keys, tried it in different devices but it never works, even though the source code is the same and so are the signing keys. I also double checked the SHA keys on google play console. I checked my proguard rules and firebase is included properly. I double checked all the needed signing keys, and ensured everything is added to my firebase project- and I added the changed google-services.json file. To ensure android studio is syncing the new google-servies file, I cleaned and rebuilt the project.

What could I be missing? Firebase support team also has no idea why this is happening even though google-services.json file is correct. It worked for all previous versions, I made a small change and suddenly it doesn't work anymore (the change wasn't related to firebase).
I'm really stuck, any change would be much much appreciated.